# Internal links in rmarkdown don't work

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I use rmarkdown to render pdf documents. Now I want to add internal links in the texts.

In the helping pages of [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#links), it says an internal link is defined as:

```
See the [Introduction](#introduction).
```

When I Use e.g. the next code there should be two internal links: link1 and link2. Both don't link. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

````
   ---
title: "Test"
author: "test test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  html_document:
    css: tables.css
    number_sections: yes
    theme: cerulean
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
subtitle: test test test
mainfont: Calibri Light
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{this is a fancy foot}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{here}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \captionsetup{skip=2pt,labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
---

# start

```{r results="asis",tidy=FALSE,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment = NA}
cat("click here: [link1](#test 1)")
```

click here: [link2](#test 1)

\pagebreak

#test 3

\pagebreak

#test 2

\pagebreak

#test 1
````

Comment: For the future reader, [this thread and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39293457/7941188)  is especially useful - it shows how to use explicit references in pandoc

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're not setting the anchors correctly.

Try the following:

````
# start

```{r results="asis",tidy=FALSE,eval=TRUE}
cat("click here: [link1](#test1)")
```

click here: [link2](#test1)

\pagebreak

# test 3 {#test3}

\pagebreak

#test 2 {#test2}

\pagebreak

#test 1 {#test1}
````

Comment: Though it's rather strange that in rmarkdown tutorial no anchors are mentioned. Instead it says: "To link to another section of the same document, use the automatically generated identifier "

Comment: @user1983395, Didn't check the documentation. I know that in HTML, they are usually called anchors, but maybe "identifiers" are more accurate.

Comment: thought it may be worth mentioning, although not particularly for this example, but I tested doing links such as (#1) and this will not work, it must start with a valid variable name like in C/Java so has to be (#quest1)

Comment: it is possible to set achors for `### headings` ?

Answer (score 29):

There are some tricky rules for internal links in Rmarkdown PDF output, not well documented on cheat sheets, etc.

Rules:

- Only one `#` for anchor, even if you are using a header with multiple `#`.

  Example: `###header` becomes `#header` when linking.
- No spaces between # and anchor text.

  Example: `#header`, not `# header`.
- Multi-word anchors should be separated by dashes.

  Example: `#this is a header` needs to become `#this-is-a-header` in the link.
- Anchor links need to be lowercase, even if the header you are linking to has capitalization.

  Example: `#Section` becomes `#section` in the link.

Answer (score 6):

@rPirate has a good list, but it was missing a case that was befuddling me.  I had a section header like `### 1.1.1 My Section Title` that needs to be `#my-section-title` in the link.

After some searching, I found an official list of transformation rules in the [Pandoc manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-auto_identifiers):

> The default algorithm used to derive the identifier from the header text is:
>
> - Remove all formatting, links, etc.
> - Remove all footnotes.
> - Remove all non-alphanumeric characters, except underscores, hyphens, and periods.
> - Replace all spaces and newlines with hyphens.
> - Convert all alphabetic characters to lowercase.
> - Remove everything up to the first letter (identifiers may not begin with a number or punctuation mark).
> - If nothing is left after this, use the identifier section.
>
> Thus, for example,
>
> ```
> Header                      | Identifier
> --------------------------------------------------------
> Header identifiers in HTML  | header-identifiers-in-html
> Maître d'hôtel              | maître-dhôtel
> *Dogs*?--in *my* house?     | dogs--in-my-house
> [HTML], [S5], or [RTF]?     | html-s5-or-rtf
> 3. Applications             | applications
> 33                          | section
> ```

Answer (score 5):

**Here is a simple way of doing internal links/references in an RMarkdown PDF document:**

A) Create a section header:

```
## Homework Assignments{#hwks}
```

B) After creating the section header. I can refer to it in my text like this:

```
If you are having a hard time with your [homework](#hwks), we have some tutors who can help you.
```

This creates a link back to the section header entitled "Homework Assignments".

**Notice a couple of things in the way I set up the link:**

1. "homework" ==> the word (or phrase) I use to call the header is in brackets
2. [homework] is immediately followed by the identifier "#hwks" that I created above, but the identifier is now in parentheses, as in: (#hwks)

This always works for me!

(This was my first post here; I hope it makes sense. :) )

Answer (score 3):

Josh Paulson has an article on Rstudio website that goes into details. Here is his solution

```
Slide 1
====================================
id: slide1

Slide 2
====================================
[Go to slide 1](#/slide1)
```

This works me. A Handcart And Mohair's code does not work on RHTML

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to compile a lot of the information across multiple different posts into a single-answer, working .Rmd file example below:

````
---
title: "internal link testing"
output: html_document
---

Create some headings that we want to link to later: 

# Heading 1

## Heading 2

### Heading  3

Improperly created headings will not work because there must be a space between the hash (#) and the heading text: 

#Heading1a    
##Heading2a    
###Heading3a    


The following links work as expected regardless of capitalization: 
[Heading 1] [heading 1] 
[Heading 2] [heading 2] 
[Heading  3] [heading  3] 

But, do not replace space(s) with dash(es)... these links will not work: 
[heading-1] [Heading-1]
[heading-2] [Heading-2]
[heading--3] [Heading--3]


*HOWEVER... * 

If using an explicit link, you MUST:   
- replace spaces with dash   
- use lower case    
- and there must be no leading space between the hash and the text:    

[explicit heading 1 link](#heading-1) 
 
Leaving in space(s) creates a broken link leading to something that doesn't exist: 
[broken heading 1 link](#heading 1) 
[broken heading 1 link](# heading-1) 

You can create links within a code chunk as well by `cat`ting or pasting the text and setting results='asis': 

```{r testchunk, results='asis', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

# These all work: 
cat("[Heading 1] [heading 1] [explicit heading 1 link](#heading-1) ")
paste("[Heading 1] [heading 1] [explicit heading 1 link](#heading-1) ")
cat('<a href="#heading-1">heading 1 href</a>')

library(DT)
library(dplyr)

for(car in unique(rownames(mtcars))) {

  # You can programmatically create section headers within a for loop, but make sure to include some extra newlines: 
  
  cat("\n")
  cat(paste0("## ", car))
  cat("\n")

  # within a kable, make sure to replace spaces, use lowercase, and set escape=FALSE
  # and remember to print the table within the loop 
  mtcars %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var="vname") %>%
    mutate(link = paste0('<a href="#', tolower(gsub(" ", "-", car)), '">', car, '</a>')) %>%
    filter(vname == car) %>%
    knitr::kable(escape=FALSE) %>%
    print()
}


# if using DT::datatable, make sure to specify escape=F to allow html within the table:
mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var="vname") %>%
  mutate(link = paste0('<a href="#', tolower(gsub(" ", "-", vname)), '">', vname, '</a>')) %>%
  datatable(escape=FALSE)
````