# Use internal links in RMarkdown HTML output

Tags: html, r-markdown, knitr

I am using R Studio to create a Rmarkdown (.Rmd) document.
I tried:

```html
Jump to [Header 1](#anchor)
```

I would like to set up a link so when a reader clicks it, they jump to a specific point on the page.

Let's say the point I want them to be directed to has a header "`## Test`".

Comment: "Jump to [test]", "Jump to [Test]" should both work for html output.  If you want to specify different display text then "[some text](#test)" would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution for HTML documents using jQuery:

```
---
title: "Internal Links"
output: html_document
---

# First Section

## Second Section

### Third Section


<script type="text/javascript">
  // When the document is fully rendered...
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // ...select all header elements...
    $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5').each(function() {
      // ...and add an id to them corresponding to their 'titles'
      $(this).attr('id', $(this).html());
    });
  });
</script>


<a href="#First Section">Go to first section</a><br>
<a href="#Second Section">Go to second section</a><br>
<a href="#Third Section">Go to third section</a>
```

As the comments point out, we simply select all headers, read out their content (e.g. "First Section") and add the attribute `id` with the value corresponding to the specific content to each header.
Now you can link to any header using `#HEADER` (e.g. `#First Section`).

---

This is of course extendable to all other elements you wish to put an anchor on. So if you want to link to any of your chunks, simply add this script to your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre.r').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr('id', 'Chunk_' + i);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now you can link to the chunks by using `<a href="Chunk_i">My Chunk</a>` where `i` goes from 0, the first chunk, to `N`, the very last chunk in your document.

Comment: This helped me turn a figure into a link to elsewhere within a shiny dashboard. Thank you!

Answer (score 84):

Pandoc supports explicit and implicit section references for headers; see [the pandoc manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#header-identifiers).

- explicit: you give a custom name to a header `## Test {#test}` and later refer to it with a link syntax: `see [the relevant section](#test)`.
- implicit: headers where you don't set a custom name, like `## Test`, can still be refered to: `See the section called [Test]`.

Both syntax should allow you to click on the link to go to the anchor, and should work in most output format. (only tested with html and pdf).

```
---
output:  pdf_document
---

## A section

blah blah

## A second section with a custom identifier {#custom}

blah blah

## Links

You can use implicit references to refer to sections
you have not explicitly named, like this: 
see [A section]. 

You can use links to refere to sections with explicit
references, like this: see [the second section](#custom).
```

Comment: In a large bookdown document (300 pages) implicit links like `[Test]` sometimes  works, and sometimes  are not linked (even the same link!) in the PDF format because in the intermediate latex file are converted to  `{[}Test{]}`. Headers and links are single words without spaces, hyphens, tildes or any strange character. Some idea of what happening and if there are some solution?

Comment: In a large document, titles may not be unique, so maybe that is the problem. Other than that I have no idea. Maybe you should write a minimal example reproducing this error and ask a new question?

Comment: Is not the case, but moreover, duplicate titles must have different automatic anchors, like "test", "test-1", "test-2", so a link  like [Test] will match only for the first one.

Comment: We can note the anchor name seems to not work starting with a number . . .  starting with a letter is solid

Answer (score 3):

Edit rmarkdown file in RStudio, in the `Visual` mode, Click: Insert -> Cross Reference. You will see a list of all referencable item list in a popup window.

Alternatively, you can insert a cross reference through @ref().

Answer (score 0):

Building on @pengchy responses as the behavior was a bit different for my setup.

Using RStudio 2023.03.0+386 "Cherry Blossom" and the visual editor.

Insert -> link ; select `Heading` from the drop down.

A hyper link with text matching the selected header will appear. In image below "r species" is inline code so `r species`, which this linking does not appear to capture.

In non visual editor the syntax is simply section header text wrapped in [], which did not seem to work if defined outside of the visual editor.

[image]