# URL link to jump to heading in .R file

Tags: r, file, url, hyperlink, rstudio

I have a R file called myscript.R that contains headings like these:

```
# heading 1 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

I can open the file with a URL link like this:

```
~Documents/myscript.R
```

Is it possible to edit the above link so that it jumps to a specific heading in myscript.R?

Comment: You can do this on html documents produced by .rmd files. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281266/use-internal-links-in-rmarkdown-html-output

Comment: If it's "just a normal `.R` file", and assuming RStudio, you can look at [`strcode`](https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/strcode) to see if/how you can adapt it to your workflow (or adapt your workflow to it). I don't think your precise functionality here is (yet) enabled in an addin.