# Internal Hyperlinks

Tags: r, blogdown

I have recently written a blog post using blogdown through RStudio, and I am trying to use internal hyperlinks within the post. Specifically, I am trying to link a 'string of text' to another 'string of text' in a different section of the script.

For instance, I created a blog post that defines some functions in the first section of the document, and my goal was to link those function names to the section of the document where I give examples on using that specific function.

To clarify, it works great when I knit my Rmd; however, it stops working once the blog is posted. Although the function names still appear to be hyperlinked, you are actually brought to the home page of my website, and not the example section of the post which is what I want.  If anyone could provide any suggestions or resources I would really appreciate it! Thank you!!

Please find the blog post here (with the internal hyperlinks not working) http://sarahrsalter.com/blog/2018-02-18-dplyr/.

Here is the Rmd code:

```
+ [**select()**](#Select): evaluates a subset of specified variables 
(columns) within a dataset.

## II) Select Functions <a id="Select"></a>

### Example 1
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is the `<base href="/./">` tag in the header. That seems to break in-page links. There is some discussion of the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108836/make-anchor-links-refer-to-the-current-page-when-using-base.

Comment: Also, make sure your IDs have valid names. Spaces are not allowed in IDs.

Comment: Maybe try the syntax here rather than creating your own `<a id="">` tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913780/internal-links-in-rmarkdown-dont-work