# R Markdown internal link to tables

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a possibility to create an internal link to a table in a rmarkdown-article?
I would like to click on this link and then I automatically come to my table.

I want to set the internal link in the text in the `Empirical Results`-part for table_1.

I've already tried [@table_1] but it doesn't work.
can someone help me?
Here is my example code:

````
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "subtitle"
author: "me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
keywords: "keywords"
output:
  pdf_document:
  fig_cap: yes
  keep_tex: yes
documentclass: article
capsize: normalsize
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
spacing: doublespacing
footerdate: yes
abstract: 'Insert abstract here'
---
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}
\keywords{keywords}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
##required packages
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

# Introduction

# Literature review

# Data and Methodology

# Empirical Results

In table_1 you can see something....

[@table_1]


# Conclusions

\newpage

# References

\newpage

# Appendix

```{r echo=F, warning=F, message=F}
df1 <- tibble(column1= 1:10, column2=11:20)

table_1 <-df1%>%kable("latex",
          booktabs=T,
          caption = "example table")%>%
kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")

table_1
```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal links in rmarkdown don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913780/internal-links-in-rmarkdown-dont-work)