# Flexdashboard: set anchors for ### headings (level3)

Tags: r, anchor, flexdashboard

In flexdashbard, we can create different headings:

- Heading level 1: they are pages
- Heading level 2: we specify `Row` or `Column`
- Heading level 3: tabs

Now for anchors, it seems that we can only set them for heading level 1. As we can see it in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913780/internal-links-in-rmarkdown-dont-work).

My question is, it is possible to create anchors for tabs (so heading level 3)?

I tried to find a solution. For example, with the following code:

```
Page 4
=====================================

## Row {.tabset}

### tab 1 {#test1}

### tab 2 {#test2}
```

The anchor is automatically created for "Page 4" which is `#page-4`. For "tab 1", I tried to add `{#test1}`, but it doesn't work.

**EDIT: solution with javascript**

Another solution that would work for me is to use javascript, to go the the next tab.

First we can add a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.btnNext').click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

</script>
```

Then, we can create buttons to navigate

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
```

But I testd in R Markdown, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

I now figured out a way to go from `#page-4` `#test1` to `#page-5` `#test4` by clicking a link. I use a bit of javascript to read the URLs parameters. This allows us to define links like `a(href="?page5&tab=4")`. The javascript will get the parameters, in our case `page` as `5` and `tab` as `4` and then execute two clicks, one to get to `#page-5` and another one to get the tab 4 called `#test4`. There are probably better options which allow you to set the active page tab and tabset tab, but I didn't get them working with {flexdashboard}. Anyway, I hope the approach below solves your problem.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill

---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(htmltools)
```

```{js}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var page = url.searchParams.get('page');
var pageid = '#page-'.concat(url.searchParams.get('page'));
var tab = 'tab'.concat(url.searchParams.get('tab'));
var tabid = '#test'.concat(url.searchParams.get('tab'));

$('a[href="'+ pageid +'"]').click();
$('a[href="'+ tabid +'"]').click();

});
```


Page 4
=====================================

## Row {.tabset}

### tab 1 {#test1}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "?page=5&tab=4",
        shiny::actionButton("btn1",
             "go to page-5 tab4"
             ))

```


### tab 2 {#test2}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "#test1",
        shiny::actionButton("btn4",
             "go to tab1"
             ))

```


Page 5
=====================================

## Row {.tabset}

### tab 3 {#test3}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "#test4",
        shiny::actionButton("btn5",
             "go to tab4"
             ))

```

### tab 4 {#test4}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "?page=4&tab=2",
        shiny::actionButton("btn6",
             "go to page-4 tab2"
             ))
```
````

**old answer**

In my case your header level 3 anchors (`{#test1}` etc.) *are* working even when not using `runtime: shiny`.  You can change the `tabs` via action buttons, but only if you are on the same page. For example you can from `tab1` to `tab2` on `page 4` but you cannot go from `tab1` on `page 4` to `tab4` on `page 5`. But changing from `page 4` to `page 5` is again possible.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(htmltools)
```


Page 4
=====================================

## Row {.tabset}

### tab 1 {#test1}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "#test2",
        shiny::actionButton("btn1",
             "go to tab2"
             ))

 tags$a(href = "#test1",
        shiny::actionButton("btn2",
             "go to tab3 (not working)"
             ))

  tags$a(href = "#page-5",
        shiny::actionButton("btn3",
             "go to page5 (working)"
             ))

```


### tab 2 {#test2}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "#test1",
        shiny::actionButton("btn4",
             "go to tab1"
             ))

```


Page 5
=====================================

## Row {.tabset}

### tab 3 {#test3}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "#test4",
        shiny::actionButton("btn5",
             "go to tab4"
             ))

```

### tab 4 {#test4}

```{r}
 tags$a(href = "#test3",
        shiny::actionButton("btn6",
             "go to tab3"
             ))

```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I don't use shiny, and it seems that with static html files (flexdashboard generated with rmarkdown::render), the tag "#section-test1" doesn't exist. "#test1", but when specifying in the url, the corresponding tab isn't showing up.

Comment: Now I removed `runtime: shiny`. Turns out, the prefix `section-` was added by `shiny`. In my case the example above is working when rendered as HTML. However, it is still not possible to go from `page 4` `tab1` directly to `page 5` `tab4` but changing tabs on the same page and changing from one page to another is working. The example above uses {shiny}s `actionButton`, but you can basically wrap the `tags$a(...)` around anything.

Comment: Thank you TimTeaFan, the buttons work fine. but when I put direct the # in the url, for example "link_flexdashbord.html#test3", it won't work. Do you why? Thank you

Comment: The problem you are describing is the same to what I pointed out above. If the website shows `page-5` you can enter the URL `"link_flexdashbord.html#test4` and it will open up the correct tab, but when `page-5` is not open this won't work. I have an idea to make this possible using javascript and I will post an update once I got it working.

Comment: @Xiaoshi: I updated my answer with a new approach, please have a look.