# How to make a table of contents in R markdownfile

Tags: r

I have an R markdown file like the following:

```
- [Introduction](#Introduction)
- [Section One](#Section One)
- [Section Two](#Section Two)
```

I then have the names of the sections like so:

> ## Introduction
>
> (R code and text)
>
> ## Section One
>
> etc

When I knit my file then it creates visible links that underline when I hover over them. However, when I click on them it does not take me to the appropriate section in the Rmarkdown page.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add table of contents in Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957278/how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:
[Internal links in rmarkdown don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913780/internal-links-in-rmarkdown-dont-work)

Essentially, in the contents page it is like this:

```
- [Introduction](#Introduction)
```

and

```
- [Section One](#s1)
```

And then in the actual section it is like:

```
# Introduction {#Introduction}

# Section One {#s1}
```